# Why isn't the JPanel showing the ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have a `GridBagConstraints gbcImage` and a `JLabel` that is initialized like this:

```
gbcImage.gridx = 1; // column 0
gbcImage.gridy = 2; // row 2
gbcImage.ipady = 100;
gbcImage.ipadx = 100;
JLabel label = new JLabel("", null, JLabel.CENTER);
label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel.add(label, gbcImage);
```

Where panel is added to a `JFrame`.

So I implemented a `MouseListener` to the label:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

            int iRet = jfc.showOpenDialog(panel);
            if (iRet == jfc.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();

                try 
                {
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file);
                    image = new ImageIcon(bi);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
                    panel.add(label, gbcImage);
                } 
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

But it didn't work. The image doesn't show in the panel at runtime.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you specified the LayoutManager for your JPanel?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create a new JLabel. The problem is you added a new label to the panel but its default size is (0, 0) because you didn't `reavalidate()` and `repaint()` the panel.

There is no need to create a new label.

Instead you keep a reference to the original label (like you do for the panel) and then you just replace the icon:

```
image = new ImageIcon(bi);
label.setIcon( image );
```